# How to include external css files hosted on a site in a css file?

Tags: css, shopify

I'm trying to add code for a form built on some site, but the code snippet includes several css and js tags. I would like to include these in a separate file because it's messing up the design of other elements in the file that I'm trying to include it on. Currently working in shopify so I would like to include them in the custom.scss.liquid file.

here is the code snippet for the form:

```
<form action="https://zymplify.com/process_form.php" method="post" class="size-wide" _lpchecked="1">
<input type="hidden" name="campaignId" id="campaignId" value="108792">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="channel" id="channel" value="262829">
            <input type="hidden" name="appId" id="appId" value="1">
                <div style="padding: 5px;" data-title="form" class="section digi-section" data-input="">
                    <div class="row digi-row" data-equalizer="" style="display:block;" data-title="row" data-input="">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 ui-sortable column" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: inherit;">
                            <div class="element digi-subheading" style="font-size: 1.375em; position: relative;;font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;Margin-left:10px!important;" data-modal="1" data-id="" data-input="element" data-title="subheading" id="style-elementID-4" data-child="true">
                                <h3 style="margin-bottom:0px">Looking for Product Data Sheets?</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="element digi-paragraph" style="font-size:0.8em; position: relative;;font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;Margin-left:10px!important;" data-modal="1" data-id="" data-input="element" data-title="paragraph" id="style-elementID-3" data-child="true">
                                <p style="margin-bottom:0px">Request them below</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="element digi-blank" data-modal="1" data-id="" data-input="" data-title="blank" id="style-elementID-2">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="element digi-form ui-sortable p-1" data-title="form" data-input="text" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; font-size: 1em !important; line-height: 0px !important; margin-right: 0px !important; margin-left: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; border-radius:0px !important; border-width: 0px !important; top: 0px;">
                                <div class="row digi-row" data-equalizer="" data-title="row" data-input="" style="top: 0px;">
                                    <div class="column small-12 ui-sortable medium-6 large-6" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: 40px;">
                                        <div class="row not-editable nope field-container" style="padding-bottom:0px!important;">
                                            <div class="nope digi-label" data-title="label" style="display: none;">
                                                <label for="email_address" data-ele-num="3">* Email address</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="nope digi-input" data-title="input">
                                                <input type="email" name="email_address" id="email_address" value="" required="" data-ele-num="3" placeholder="* Email address">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="column small-12 ui-sortable medium-6 large-6" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: 40px;">
                                            <div class="row not-editable nope field-container" style="position: relative; opacity: 1; left: 0px; top: 0px;padding-bottom:0px!important;">
                                                <div class="nope digi-submit field-container" data-title="button" style=";;text-align:left;padding-bottom:0px!important;">
                                                    <input id="linkID-4" class="button" type="submit" value="Request Data Sheet" data-ele-num="sub" style=";;font-family:Noto Sans, sans-serif;font-size:1.0em!important;;background-color:#000000!important;width:50%;line-height:0px!important;border-radius:0px!important;">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <style type="text/css" id="input-stylesheet"> div.element input:not([type='submit']):not([type='checkbox']), div.element select {font-size:1em;}</style>
                        <style type="text/css" id="container-stylesheet"> div.input-container {}</style>
```

EDIT:
I added the external css code into a separate file and included it within my page. However, the css still overrides the pre-existing css, so I want to put all the new css in a class, like this:

```
.datasheet-form { ...new css... }
```

Comment: are links added automatically or you include them, if you include them then you override them or modify the css for third-party site by downloading it and then including with some change so that it only reflects changes for form not other elements on form. can you share more details such as code and form page or screenshot of page etc

Comment: @Learning i add the form code in the question above.

Comment: Most of your CSS have `!important` This will override any css.

Answer (score 0):

copy the content of the form-builder.css file and store it in the assets folder as `custom.scss.liquid`

On the page/template/section that you want to use the css, use this to link the css file `{{'custom.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag}}`

Comment: I don’t want to include all the code into that file because custom CSS file is Already big as it is. Lets say i add all the code into A separate file datasheet.css. Is there something i can do to include datasheet.css in customcss file for a specific class?

Comment: then create the datasheet.css file, put into asset folder and copy the content there. same solution `{{'datasheet.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag}}`.

Comment: How can I make this only apply to a certain class? Doesn’t your code do the same thing as just having the link tag?

Comment: certain class or certain page, product, template, section, snippet, etc. you need to be more specific.  The code is fine, the matter is where you put it. Learning mentioned extra css can override other css code. will need to take caution in that too. so, look for the order of the css, include the datasheet.css first and override it with the default one.

Comment: sorry i want these css files to only apply to a certain class. for example: having a <div class="datasheet-form"><form>..</form></div>, and then having the datasheet.css apply to only this div. i wrapped everything in datasheet.css in .datasheet-form{...} but it doesn't work

Comment: are use using `iframe`? if `iframe` then nothing will work since the code come from another site and should be controlled from there.

Comment: i am not using iframe. haven't heard of that before, I'm fairly new. how can I apply it to my solution?

Comment: please edit /update your question to have the code in proper format, and include everything you have done.  1 line code is extremely hard to read.